# Which CMS plugins for Wordpress should I use?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking into setting up a very simple site (static pages and an image gallery) with Wordpress for a non-web-savvy client, so I'd like to simplify the Editor role's admin interface as much as possible.

Looking through Wordpress's plugin directory, I found several plugins that "CMS-ify" the admin side of things, hiding menu options and the like. Are there any "admin-cleaning" plugins you'd recommend? Are there any other plugins I should look into?

Answer (score 3):

I keep preaching this plugin all over Stackoverflow, but seriously go with [PodsCMS](http://www.podscms.org/). It rocks the house with it's features, scalability, and developer support. There is good documentation and accessible Q&A from the developers via the Pods Forum, IRC Chat, and even Twitter.

To simplify the Editor role (or any role) check out [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/).

Comment: I've used the combination of PodsCMS and Adminimize in several sites.  Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

- http://wp-cms.com/our-wordpress-plugins/wp-cms-post-control-plugin/
- http://www.noupe.com/wordpress/powerful-cms-using-wordpress.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as plugins to limit user controls, I always use Capability Manager (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/). It allows you to grant or revoke any/all capabilities for any/all roles. You can also create your own role types with their own capabilities. As far as CMS-ifying your WP, you can set static pages as the front page and create galleries by default. There are also plenty of plugins to insert lightbox or thickbox, or what have you to add very nice looking UI for your galleries:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-2/

That's just a few.

Comment: I really like Next Gen gallery too.  I've used it many times and always been satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Adminimize or Capability Manager as recommended by others.

PodsCMS is impressive, bit is going to be rendered more or less obsolete with WordPress 3.0, which is coming out very soon.  So I would not be starting with that system right now.